# img tag convert into div tag by using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change all img tag of a page into div tag by using jQuery.
ex.

```
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/img.png" alt="this text i want in div" />
```

by using jQuery it converts into

```
<div>this text i want in div</div>
```

How we can do this by using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Am75c/

```
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/img.png" alt="this text i want in div1" />
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/img.png" alt="this text i want in div2" />
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/img.png" alt="this text i want in div3" />

$('img').each(function(){
    $div = $('<div>').html($(this).attr('alt'));
    $(this).replaceWith($div);
});
```