# img tag convert into div tag by using javascript

Tags: image, html, tags

A similar question : [img tag convert into div tag by using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054079/img-tag-convert-into-div-tag-by-using-jquery)

I want to do exactly the same thing but without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

look this code maybe help you

```
 function replaceSrc()
  {

   var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
     for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
      {
         var img = images[i];
         if(img.src.length == 0)
         {
          img.src = 'blank.jpg';
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: It's not good for me, I need to hide the image and write text Instead. I could only find all images on the page and hide them and What I have left to do is to write text instead of images